# How to understand "normal" in mapping node in shader editor?

Tags: shaders

Sorrey i can't precisely control the texture and texture coordinate.

Please help me and tell me how the vector(normal) of the object match the position of the texture?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The "normal" type mapping is similar to the "vector" type mapping, in that it only does rotation and scaling and no translation.  In addition, it also normalizes the ouput vector (giving it a length of 1 while retaining its direction.)  Exactly like vector mapping and following it up with a vector math/normalize.